# Why am I able to override some methods from java.sql.Connection and not others

Tags: java, sql, import, connection, overriding

I am building a simple JDBC Driver for a text base as an exercise for a class. I've imported the source code provided to eclipse and in one class it seems that I am able to override some methods from java.sql.Connection but for the last few in the class.

[image: my import statements]

[image: Methods that wont override]

When I mouse over the error the warning reads:

"The method abort(Executor) of type TextDBConnection must override or implement a a supertype method.
1 Quick fix available:
remove @Override"

If I remove @Override the error goes away and it's not necessary for the exercise, but none of my classmates got this error when they imported the starting code and I'm curious as to what the cause of the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [abort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#abort%28java.util.concurrent.Executor%29), [getNetworkTimeout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getNetworkTimeout%28%29) and [getSchema](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getSchema%28%29) methods were added in Java 7. Perhaps you are using an older version of Java, in which these methods didn't exist, so you can't override them.

Answer (score 0):

[getNetworkTimeout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getNetworkTimeout--) mentions in the javadoc that it was added in Java 1.7 So my guess is that you're using / compiling with a version of Java 1.6 or lower